# Can you pass an additional parameter to a predicate?

Tags: c++, predicate

I'm trying to filter a vector so it contains only a specific value.

e.g. Make sure the vector only contains elements of the value "abc."

Right now, I'm trying to achieve this with `remove_copy_if`.

Is there any way to pass an additional parameter to a predicate when using one of std's algorithms?

```
std::vector<std::string> first, second;
first.push_back("abc");
first.push_back("abc");
first.push_back("def");
first.push_back("abd");
first.push_back("cde");
first.push_back("def");

std::remove_copy_if(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), is_invalid);
```

I'm hoping to pass the following function as a predicate but it seems more likely that this would just end up comparing the current value being examined by `remove_copy_if` and the next.

```
bool is_invalid(const std::string &str, const std::string &wanted)
{
   return str.compare(wanted) != 0;
}
```

I have a feeling I'm probably approaching this wrong so any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering - what do you use a vector with only identical elements for?

Comment: I tried to make my example as simple as possible so it made sense :) What I did with this was to remove elements from a vector that fit a certain pattern (with regex).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Define a functor instead:

```
struct is_invalid
{
    is_invalid(const std::string& a_wanted) : wanted(a_wanted) {}
    std::string wanted;
    bool operator()(const std::string& str)
    {
        return str.compare(wanted) != 0;
    }
};

std::remove_copy_if(first.begin(),
                    first.end(),
                    second.begin(),
                    is_invalid("abc"));
```

or if C++11 use a lambda:

```
std::string wanted("abc");
std::remove_copy_if(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), 
    [&wanted](const std::string& str)
    {
        return str.compare(wanted) != 0;
    });
```

Note that the output vector, `second`, *must* have elements before the call to `remove_copy_if()`:

```
// Create 'second' after population of 'first'.
//
std::vector<std::string> second(first.size());

std::string wanted = "abc";
int copied_items    = 0;
std::remove_copy_if( first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(),
    [&wanted, &copied_items](const std::string& str) -> bool
    {
        if (str.compare(wanted) != 0) return true;
        copied_items++;
        return false;
    });
second.resize(copied_items);
```

As functor predicates are copied more effort is required to retain the `copied_items` information. See [Pass std algos predicates by reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313370/pass-std-algos-predicates-by-reference-in-c) for suggested solutions.

Comment: I seem to get an error about an "undefined reference" when I try to use this solution, any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: @noko, can you post you code to ideone or similar? Note you compiler must support C++11 lambdas (in g++ you need to use `-std=c++0x` compiler switch).

Comment: never mind, I forgot to add a ClassName:: before the function :(

Answer (score 10):

Make functor, or use `std/boost::bind`.

```
struct is_invalid
{
public:
   is_invalid(const std::string& w):wanted(w) { }
   bool operator () (const std::string& str)
   {
       return str.compare(wanted) != 0;
   }
private:
   std::string wanted;
};

std::remove_copy_if(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), is_invalid("abc"));
```

Example with bind

```
bool is_invalid(const std::string &str, const std::string &wanted)
{
   return str.compare(wanted) != 0;
}

std::remove_copy_if(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(),
boost::bind(is_invalid, _1, "abc"));
```